# How to save a file on server running Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

I have a server running Node.js. I have to read form data from html page ("index.html") and write that data to a txt file.

This is my index.html:

```
<form action="/uploads" method="post">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td><img src="images/ktulogo.png" width="100" height="100"></td>
         <td>
            <h3>Karadeniz Teknik Üniversitesi Bilgisayar Mühendisliği Bölümü</h3>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><br></td>
         <td>
            <hr>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <h4>Adınız Soyadınız :</h4>
         </td>
         <td><input type="text" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 40%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <h4>Öğrenci Numaranız :</h4>
         </td>
         <td><input name="ogrNo" type="text" style="margin-left: 5%; width: 40%"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <h4>Cevabınız :</h4>
         </td>
         <td><textarea name="answer" datatype="text" rows="10" cols="100" style="margin-left: 5%; resize: none"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </br>
   <center>
      <button id="saveFile" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 30%">Sisteme Yükle</button>
   </center>
</form>
```

And here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/index.html'));
});

app.post('/uploads', function (req, res) {
    var file_name = req.body.ogrNo;
    var file_content = req.body.answer;
    file_content = file_content.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");

    var stream = fs.createWriteStream(file_name+".txt");
    stream.once('open', function () {
        stream.write(file_content);
        stream.end();
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

And when I run this, it throws me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ogrNo' of undefined
>      at c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\app.js:13:27
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at next (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
>      at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>      at c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
>      at Function.process_params (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
>      at next (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
>      at serveStatic (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
>      at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\Volkan\IdeaProjects\File Upload\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

So, what is the cause of my problem or how I can handle this job?

Comment: check your request !

Comment: body is undefined. You'r missing https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: I handle it ! You're right @BorisCharpentier, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse incoming data, for that purpose use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

First install it

```
npm i -S body-parser
```

Then import it to your code

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
```

Add parsers

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

That's all.

Comment: Maybe in 2017 it's better to use const than var. Maybe not. Any idea ?

Comment: Sure it's better to use `const` for such things, but it makes no sense for this case :)